# Saving model with description in keras

Tags: python, keras

I would like to write out a keras model that contains a description (can be a simple string), so that one can more easily keep track of what a file contains.

Is there any simple way to do this? I can save and load a model with

```
model.save(filename)
[...]
model = keras.load_model(filename)
```

what I would like to do, is something to the effect of

```
model.save(filename, description=string)
[...]
model, description = keras.load_model(filename)
```

Any ideas on what would be the simplest way of achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no way to do this with the current version of `model.save` in the Keras. It just saves the configuration of the model() such as `loss function`  and `metrics` and `load_model` just returns what has been saved.

One nasty solution to this problem is manually adding a `description` variable to the class `models.py` in Keras and consequently, add the required lines of code to the `save_model` and `load_model` functions. Again, this is just a horrible solution!